# What could cause an "update to ... inside a test was not wrapped in act" despite using act?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm doing my first steps with testing React functional components with something like:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

import App from './App';

test('basic app rendering', () => {
  act(() => {
    render(<App />);
  })
});
```

However this is resulting in the infamous warning that we have to use `act`:

```
Warning: An update to SomeSubComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
      
When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
      
act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
/* assert on the output */

This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
```

The link brings me back to where I'm coming from, and basically shows an example that is using `act` exactly like I do.

I see a few possibilities:

- Something is wrong with my usage of `act`.
- Something is wrong with my test setup / configuration (I'm using basically a plain create-react-app typescript template).
- Something is wrong with the component I'm testing.

Any ideas what could lead to this situation that I get the "not wrapped in act" warning despite already wrapping in `act`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that I simply needed this:

```
test('basic app rendering', async () => {
  await act(async () => {
    render(<App />);
  })
});
```

This has been raised as an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15379) in version 16.8. Similar to that linked issue, my problem was an async function in `useEffect`.

In versions 16.9+ onwards (I'm on 17.0) an async version of `act` is available.

The reason I had asked the question is that I first made a stupid mistake trying the async variant:

```
test('basic app rendering', async () => {
  await act(() => { // note missing async here
    render(<App />);
  })
});
```

I.e., I forgot to annotate the function passed to `act` as `async` as well. In this case it doesn't work (and in fact there is a warning `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.`).